# How to migrate a database from 2016 to 2014 if there are encrypted/locked objects(SPs) associated with it?

Tags: ssms, migration, scripting, always-encrypted, locked-objects

I am trying to migrate a database from 2016 to 2014 through Task-->Generate Scripts. There are some stored procedures that are locked and seems like they are encrypted as well. They are causing error while generating the script. I have tried both schema or schema and data.

I have also tried using Task--> Export Data tier application but that is generating error related to logins.

Looking for an advice in terms of best way to do this or how to fix the above errors. Thanks in advance.[image]

Comment: Why would you want to *downgrade* to 2014, which is now out of support?

Comment: Is it your database? Can you not decrypt them?

Comment: @Charlieface the third party tool that our organization uses was not upgraded for a long time. To upgrade that, we need to follow a fixed path that involves upgrading it to a version that involves SQL 2012 or 2014.

Comment: @Rohit Gupta it was provided by the vendor and hosted on our server. Interestingly, when I contacted their support, even they could not decrypt it at their end.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you can do - skip such procedures.

If you have a source code for this procedure somewhere in your repositories and/or archives - good, take it from there. If not - alas, you will not be able to migrate it.